# Very Slow Download Speeds from Apple Applications (Safari and Mac App Store)

Tags: network, safari, mac-appstore, macos, performance

After I restored my computer to a clean reinstall of El Capitan, I have experienced incredibly slow download speeds in Apple applications only (Safari and the App Store). I tested downloading a file in safari, and I got around 256 kilobytes per second, but when downloading the exact same file with the exact same internet connection, I got much greater download speeds of around 5 to 6 megabytes per second. The same thing is happening in the App Store, with download speeds averaging around 256 kilobytes per second.

I have tried changing the DNS to both Open DNS and Google Public DNS, and none of them seem to fix the problem.

Again, I am having extremely slow download speeds only in Apple applications. (Strangely enough, browsing speeds are still very fast. Only download speeds are slow.) This is a very strange problem and I have no idea what is causing them.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: What exactly are you downloading using Safari? Same question-what is the App Store and downloading?

Comment: Whaaaat, you are complaining about 256kb/s download speed???  I'm lucky to get that on my mac!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as others are mentioning this issue might be related to a specific ISP, try enabling a VPN and re-running the download.

This mightn't be a long-term solution, but it should help you identify if the issue is the ISP performing traffic shaping App Store packets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Must be on Apple's side. Their status page doesn't list anything, but I've tried a number of DNS/other fixes to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you all using Time Warner for your internet? - I have several clients with the exact same slow issue and they all are on TW. I have Charter and don't see this issue at all.

Comment: I'm on Time Warner and experiencing extremely slow download speeds from my iPhone and iTunes on Windows.

Comment: I am using TW too and trying to download apps from the store and can't have more than 100KB/s .. Changed DNS servers to be 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.222.220 but can't see any difference. Any fix ?

Comment: I'm using Time Warner - super slow downloading from Apple today...My internet speed still shows at 200mbps though so the issue must be on Apples side.